# Simultaneous flexible vertical space with page breaks

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

Running into an issue I can't figure out. In essence, I have a page that has some text, possibly some equations, a couple graphics and maybe a table, all separated by flexible white-space. Sometimes everything fits on one page, but sometimes the graphics are too large so multiple pages are needed.

Let's say I have 3 graphics. In the case they're all to big to fit on one page, I'd expect that the first two graphics stay on the first page, distributed evenly along with any preceding text, and the third graphic would be on the next page along with the following text or tables, etc. However, my code always keeps all three graphics together.

I'm of the impression it's due to `\vspace` creating an unbreakable `vbox`, but I don't know how else to handle what I want without manually adding a `\clearpage` or similar. This is undesirable; the end goal is templates that pretty much automagically do this for me, of course!

Here's a MWE. In this example, images A and B end up on page 2. My desire is for image A to end up on page 1, and B, C and the next section on page 2.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\section{A section}

\subsection{the first subsection}

Some text here

\vfill

\begin{center}
\textbf{Some title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}

\vfill

\textbf{More title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}

\vfill

\textbf{Even more title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
\end{center}

\subsection{The next subsection}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Rough MSPaint rendition of what I expect:
[image]

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \undefinedpagestyle 
                               
l.10 \pagestyle{fancy}

Comment: don't put a \vfill before the \begin{center}. Or better replace them all by e.g. \medskip

Comment: No it must have given an error, check the log, perhaps latexmk is scrolling past by default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah yes, you're right. My mistake!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The preceding `\vfill` is there to push the `example-image-a` away from the section above it. I want the items (i.e. the first subsection and its text, the image and its caption, etc.) to be distributed evenly along the vertical axis of the page.

Comment: Fun fact: I ran into this problem again (same project) today. Googled to see if I could find an answer on how to solve it, and came across this question. Read a couple sentences and thought "this is exactly what I need!" then realized I wrote this question LOL. Can only bounty 100 points with my rep, but it's something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

What is happening in your MWE is that the interaction between infinitely stretchable skips and the negative (page break) penalty introduced by `center` is causing TeX's page breaking algorithm to conclude that there is no better place for a page break than just before the contents of the `center` environment.
This is why using `\centering` instead of the `center` environment helps.
Similar problems will still crop up around section headings and list environments, however.

A negative penalty (for page breaking) is inserted at the start of the `center` environment because it internally uses a `trivlist` and the start of a list is considered a good place for a page break.
This negative penalty encourages TeX to break the page at this point if it was already an okay place to do so, by which I mean that doing so wouldn't cause any glue to be stretched too far.
Because you've inserted some infinitely stretchable glue, however, no amount of stretching is too much, which leads to the conclusion that ending the page at the start of the `center` environment is preferable to doing so when the page is full.
There is no cost associated to putting a page break there due to the infinite stretch, but it has the benefit (in TeX's mind) that the break occurs at a natural spot for it.

A detailed description of the page breaking algorithm may be found in section 27.4 of [TeX by Topic](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf).

Apart from forced page breaks, I *think* negative penalties that are (by default) only inserted at the following places:

- above section headings,
- around list environments (which  includes `center` and e.g. theorem environments, since these are implemented using `\trivlist`),
- between `\item`s,
- by a bunch of user commands that do this explicitly (`\pagebreak[n]`, `\smallbreak`, etc.),
- other? (Someone please let me know if I missed something)

### A solution/work-around

To avoid page breaks occurring earlier than necessary due to negative penalties, you could set these negative penalties to zero.
To do this for section headings and in/around lists, add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter       %% <- make @ usable in command sequences
\@secpenalty=0      %% <- don't encourage breaks before section heading
\@beginparpenalty=0 %% <- don't encourage breaks at start of list environments
\@endparpenalty=0   %% <- don't encourage breaks at end of list environments
\@itempenalty=0     %% <- don't encourage breaks between items
\makeatother        %% <- revert @
```

A side-effect of doing this is, of course, that page breaks will no longer be encouraged at these places. (They will still be discouraged e.g. *after* section headings, however.)
This is also not going to help you if negative penalties are inserted by any other type of environment/command, so be wary of that.

I've defined a version of the `figure` environment that I think does more or less what you want (provided all of the above penalties are set to zero).
Infinitely stretchable that can't move over to the previous/next page will be inserted around it.
You could similarly define a `shamtamtable` environment for tables.

```
\newcommand*\topvfill{%
  \par                      %% <- switch to vertical mode
  \penalty 0                %% <- allow a page break here, but don't encourage it
  \vspace*{0pt plus 1fill}% %% <- unremovable infinitely stretchable space
}
\newcommand*\bottomvfill{%
  \par                      %% <- switch to vertical mode
  \vspace{0pt plus 1fill}%  %% <- infinitely stretchable space
  \penalty 0                %% <- allow a page break here
}

\usepackage{float} % <- for the [H] option
\newenvironment{shamtamfig}{%
  \topvfill    %% <- insert flexible space above
  \figure[H]%  %% <- begin inner figure environment
  \centering   %% <- horizontally centre content
}{%
  \endfigure   %% <- end figure environment
  \bottomvfill %% <- insert flexible space below
}
```

### Your MWE with these changes

Here is your MWE with `\vfill` replaced by `\beakablevfill` and with the aforementioned negative penalties set to zero.
I've added the `showframe` option to `geometry` to show the border of the text area and I've made a few minor changes to make this demonstration clearer.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in, showframe]{geometry} %% <- added showframe for demonstration
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command sequences
\@beginparpenalty=0 % <- start of list env
\@endparpenalty=0   % <- end of list env
\@itempenalty=0     % <- between items
\@secpenalty=0      % <- before section heading
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

\newcommand*\topvfill{%
  \par                      %% <- switch to vertical mode
  \penalty 0                %% <- allow a page break here, but don't encourage it
  \vspace*{0pt plus 1fill}% %% <- unremovable infinitely stretchable space
}
\newcommand*\bottomvfill{%
  \par                      %% <- switch to vertical mode
  \vspace{0pt plus 1fill}%  %% <- infinitely stretchable space
  \penalty 0                %% <- allow a page break here
}
\def\midvfill{%
  \par                       %% <- switch to vertical mode
  \vspace{0pt plus 1fill}%   %% <- infinitely stretchable space
  \penalty 0                 %% <- allow a page break here, but don't encourage it
  \vspace{0pt plus -1fill}%  %% <- cancels out the previous \vspace if no page break occurred
  \vspace*{0pt plus 1fill}%  %% <- unbreakable/unremovable infinitely stretchable space
}

\usepackage{float} % <- for the [H] option

\newenvironment{shamtamfig}{%
  \topvfill    %% <- insert flexible space above
  \figure[H]%  %% <- begin inner figure environment
  \centering   %% <- horizontally centre content
}{%
  \endfigure   %% <- end figure environment
  \bottomvfill %% <- insert flexible space below
}

\usepackage{blindtext} % <- for demonstration purposes

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\subsection{the first subsection}

\blindtext[2]

\blindtext

\begin{shamtamfig}
    \textbf{Some title text}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{shamtamfig}

\begin{shamtamfig}
    \textbf{More title text}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{shamtamfig}

\begin{shamtamfig}
    \textbf{Even more title text}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{shamtamfig}

\subsection{The next subsection}

\blindtext

\blinditemize

\blindtext[2]

\begin{shamtamfig}
    \textbf{Even more title text}\par
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{shamtamfig}

\end{document}
```

For fun, you can try commenting out a few of the `\@...penalty=0` lines in this example to see what effect these lines have.

[image: first page]
[image: second page]
[image: third page]

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll cycle back in the next day or two after I've had a chance to try it out and see if this works for my actual use case. +1 for the excellent explanation of what TeX is actually doing!

Comment: Take your time. This was quite tricky, so I may have overlooked some other problem.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

%\pagestyle{fancy}

\mainmatter

\section{A section}

\subsection{the first subsection}

Some text here

\vfill

{\centering
\textbf{Some title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}


\vfill

\textbf{More title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}

\vfill

\textbf{Even more title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}

}

\subsection{The next subsection}

\end{document}
```

You get slightly luckier with `\centering` but really the issue is using `\\*` rather than proper sectioning or `\item` commands. In the scope of `\centering` (and `center`) `\\` is really `\par` rather than its usual definition of `\newline` that means it exercises the page breaker, `\\*` adds a `\nobreak` penalty, so if it happens that a page break is considered after the heading a break is prevented there because of the `*` but a zero penalty break is available before the first image due to the `\vfill` being available to fill the space, so TeX takes that page break rather than looking ahead.

---

A perhaps better markup avoiding using explicit spacing font changes and `\\` in favour of the more idiomatic latex `\caption` markup would be

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe,float}

\begin{document}

%\pagestyle{fancy}

\mainmatter

\section{A section}

\subsection{the first subsection}

Some text here

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
\caption{Some title text}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}  
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
\caption{Some title text}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}  
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
\caption{Some title text}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}  
\end{figure}



\subsection{The next subsection}

\end{document}
```

You can use the facilities of the float (and related `caption`) to customise the caption formatting as required.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely (un)luck. In my actual document, I'm using a localized `\centering` block exactly as in your example, in fact! Your explanation about the `\\*` definitely makes sense to me though. Is using multiple `figure`s the best solution to this, or are there other solutions? I'm not very well-versed in (La)TeX, if it's not obvious ;)

Comment: @Shamtam I added a second suggestion

Comment: I'll try playing with figures and seeing how that works out. The second example leaves a lot of white space below `example-image-a`, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like the image to be distributed vertically along with the text in the section above it when a page break directly follows it, see the rough rendition in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean "flexible white space" but you could define a new command that would use `\vspace` with a predefined "flexible length".

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{20pt plus 10pt minus 5pt}
\newcommand{\myskip}{\vspace{\mylength}}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\section{A section}

\subsection{the first subsection}

Some text here

\myskip

\begin{center}
\textbf{Some title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}

\myskip

\textbf{More title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}

\myskip

\textbf{Even more title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
\end{center}

\subsection{The next subsection}

\end{document}
```

PS: Not sure if I understood the question, so, feel free to ask me to delete it.

Comment: Apologies for my poor explanation. By "flexible white space" I mean a white-space that expands to fill the `vbox` it's contained in, e.g. if I have two paragraphs with a `\vfill` between them, the top paragraph will anchor to the top of the page, and the second to the bottom. My problem is that if I use something like `\vspace{0.1in plus 1fil}`, instead of breaking after the first image, it breaks before the first image instead.

Comment: Thanks for explaining... I could not see the reason of that \vfill before. Deleting the answer in 5'

Comment: @koleygr don't delete I was just going to tell the OP to do this!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle... I think that this answer doesn't help him with the request of having figures only on top and bottom... If the figures are small enough they could leave empty space at the bottom and thus the answer doesn't give the required output. (Already upvoted your answer but this one will just waste the time of future readers)

Comment: @koleygr my answer isn't an answer at all really I just changed center to centering which affects the space before the first image and then gets luck with the page breaks in this example. Perhaps we both delete and let someone else have a go:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `center` it is better to put each block into its own environment.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}    
\mainmatter    
\section{A section}    
\subsection{the first subsection}    
Some text here    
\vfill    
\begin{center}
\textbf{Some title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{center}    
\vfill    
\begin{center}
\textbf{More title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\end{center}    
\vfill    
\begin{center}
\textbf{Even more title text} \\*
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
\end{center}    
\subsection{The next subsection}    

\end{document}
```